# How to write an own credentialProvider for withCredentials step

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, credentials

We use the [`withCredentials`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-binding-plugin) step in our pipelines and would like to have a custom retriever for it that can hide username/passwords that came from a http request.

How can I provide my own function to retrieve the username/password?